# How to check if string is nonsense or set of english words

Tags: encryption, caesar-cipher, vigenere

I am trying to crack [Vigenère cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) from school homework by brute-force and I want to write my own script for it, because I have no information about KEY.

Is there any tool what can check how much real english words is included in input string?

**Example:**

This string is nonsense: 'GHDSGBHJWVHUSAFRSFUYWFBDYFTSA'

This string seems like proper OPEN TEXT: 'THENAMETOOOFTENSTOREMANAGER'

Any existing packages for Javascript, Java or Python? Or some public API what can tell me how much if any words found?

Comment: The Wikipedia page you linked to has a section on cryptanalysis. First you need to determine the key length. Then you can use frequency analysis fo figure out what the actual key is. Is there some particular aspect of this you're having trouble with?

Comment: That was not my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply feed a plaintext dictionary of English words into a regex comparison with each known word against the string. Then you can do your logic after that to determine if you think it's a real English string or not.

Comment: Yea... I did this but it is not very efficient :D

Comment: Not sure exactly how you went about that, but I am sure there are ways to make it much faster with threading for example.

Answer (score 2):

What you probably need is **nostril**. Nostril is the Nonsense String Evaluator: a Python module that infers whether a given short string of characters is likely to be random gibberish or something.

https://github.com/casics/nostril

```
from nostril import nonsense

if nonsense('yoursinglestringhere'):
   print("nonsense")
else:
   print("real")
```